# Terraform aws identity_source

Tags: terraform, amazon-api-gateway

How can I disable the default `identity_source` when deploying an API Gateway Lambda authorizer using Terraform?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "authorizer" {
  name                             = "authorizer"
  type                             = "REQUEST"
  rest_api_id                      = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}"
  authorizer_uri                   = "${local.authorizer_invoke_arn}"
  authorizer_result_ttl_in_seconds = 0
}
```

It seems Terraform uses `method.request.header.Authorization` as the default for `identity_source`.

I can go in an remove this manually from the API Gateway console, but I'm not sure how to remove identity source altogether using Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `identity_source` is optional it should be possible to pass in an empty string.

The Terraform Provider does not validate the field as [hinted by the code](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/24e937a299c9115be47052404a97d6c9d5a4ccfa/aws/resource_aws_api_gateway_authorizer.go#L78)